# Beamer footnote problem

Tags: beamer

I am trying to make a presentation using beamer in latex. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,CambridgeUS ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\title[Presentation of Thesis]{\textbf{ME 400: Thesis and Project}}
\author{Moinuddin Shuvo (1210092)\\ Md. Badrul Hasan (1210099)\\ Rabiul Hasan Kabir (1210100)}

%\author{Chitra Lakhotia (PRN:13030142076)\\}

\institute{{\Large Bangladesh Universitiy of Engineering \& Technology}}
%\textsc {Industrial Training Presentation }

\date{$10^{\text{th}}$ September 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

The problem is my footnote shows half the name of the authors (3 authors in this case) I just want to show the institute name in the left side of my footnote (in place of author's name). 
here is the attached view of present document :

[image]

Comment: You could use `\author[short name for footline]{...}`

Comment: In that case, my Institute name also shows up, Is there any way by which I can omit the author name and only include the Institute name in my left side footer?

Comment: To completely remove the author name, leave `short name for footline` empty.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter it worked :) will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: the content of the footline can be set independently from the content of the titlepage by specifying an optional argument in `\author[short version for footline]{long version for title page}`

---

A few other comments:

- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- never use formatting instruction in arguments. If you want the `\institute` to be in `\Large` or the title in bold use

  ```
  \setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
  \setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\Large}
  ```

  instead.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,CambridgeUS ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


\title[Presentation of Thesis]{ME 400: Thesis and Project}

\author[Bangladesh Universitiy]{\texorpdfstring{%
    Moinuddin Shuvo (1210092)\\ Md. Badrul Hasan (1210099)\\ Rabiul Hasan Kabir (1210100)
}{
    Moinuddin Shuvo (1210092) Md. Badrul Hasan (1210099) Rabiul Hasan Kabir (1210100)
}}

\institute[]{Bangladesh Universitiy of Engineering \& Technology}

\date{$10^{\text{th}}$ September 2017}

\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\Large}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]